# Conflict between 2 libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-switch

I have a conflict with android-switch-backport and android-betterpickers because both override the style "switchStyle" and "switchPreferenceStyle". 
I want to use both of libraries (because the switch android-switch-backport have more possibilities )

I'm using android-studio . my app is supporting Android Api 10 .
If anyone have an idea of how i can resolve this conflict ...

Comment: can u use namesspace for each class like this ? 
com.test.packagename.TheClassName

Comment: where can i use it ? the libraries are imported via gradle and i'm not overriding (yet) those fields "switchStyle" and "switchPreferencesStyle"

Comment: Now i can see that android-betterpickers using a package from android-switch-backport the new question is "how to exclude a package from a library on gradle ?" and i don't know if this can resolve it..

Comment: My solution doesn't work (Obviously) because it isn't the package that matter, is the fact that it was overrode in Style.xml in both libs..